# help with registering MVC3 route

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, httphandler

i have web application that i wants to map two URL path

first 
{domain} ex :- www.youdomian.com for home page
{domain}/{id} :- www.youdomain.com/1234 for second page
also have httphandler 
how can i registered this route

this is what  have done. i commented the first line to get work httphandler

```
//routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
routes.MapRoute("Shorten", "{id}", new {controller = "SecondPage", action = "Index"});

routes.MapRoute("Default", // Route name
                "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
```

problem is when i call handler it's redirected to secondpage route how can i by pass this